# encfs with expect access denied

Tags: permissions, expect, encfs

If I execute script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
set pass [lindex $argv 0] 
spawn encfs -v  {CRIPT_DIR}  {MNT_DIR} -o nonempty 
expect "*EncFS Password:*"
send "$pass\r"
expect eof
```

expect script output:

```
zz@zz-com:/media/truecrypt5/mmm$./e.sh 1
spawn encfs -v /media/truecrypt5/mmm/cr /media/truecrypt5/mmm/mn -o nonempty
10:25:11 (main.cpp:523) Root directory: /media/truecrypt5/mmm/cr/
10:25:11 (main.cpp:524) Fuse arguments: (daemon) (threaded) (keyCheck) encfs /media/truecrypt5/mmm/mn -o nonempty -s -o use_ino -o default_permissions 
10:25:11 (FileUtils.cpp:177) version = 20
10:25:11 (FileUtils.cpp:181) found new serialization format
10:25:11 (FileUtils.cpp:199) subVersion = 20100713
10:25:11 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
10:25:11 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 24, ivlength 16
10:25:11 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
10:25:11 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 24, ivlength 16
10:25:11 (FileUtils.cpp:1620) useStdin: 0
EncFS Password: 
10:25:11 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
10:25:11 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 24, ivlength 16
10:25:12 (FileUtils.cpp:1628) cipher key size = 44
10:25:12 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if nameio/block(3:0:1) implements nameio/block(3:0:0)
```

ls command:

```
zz@zz-com:/media/truecrypt5/mmm$sudo ls -la
[sudo] password for zz: 
ls: cannot access mn: Permission denied
total 24
drwx------  4 zz zz 4096 2012-08-31 14:40 .
drwx------ 10 zz zz 4096 1970-01-01 03:00 ..
drwx------  2 zz zz 4096 2012-08-30 18:56 cr
-rwx------  1 zz zz   73 2012-08-30 18:54 e2.sh
-rwx------  1 zz zz  178 2012-08-30 19:10 e.sh
d?????????  ? ?  ?     ?                ? mn
-rwx------  1 zz zz   40 2012-08-30 18:52 u.sh
```

I don't have access to {MNT_DIR}. Sodo user don't have access to. But command or shell scipt

```
#!/bin/sh
encfs -v  {CRIPT_DIR}  {MNT_DIR} -o nonempty
```

work correct.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

What is wrong in my expect script?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What has `sudo` got to do with scripting the password for `encfs`? Do you mean that something is different depending on whether you use expect or not? What is different?

Comment: I mean that even sudo (root) user don't have access.

Comment: But does root have access when you don't use expect? And does the mounting work (i.e. do *you* have access) when you use expect?

Comment: Yes mounting work without expect./n encfs -v  {CRIPT_DIR}  {MNT_DIR} -o nonempty --- WORK

Answer (score 2):

Nothing's wrong with your expect script. But it looks like you used your regular user to mount the encrypted directory, and then you are trying to see the mounted files with root using sudo. That will not work, and is the whole point of encfs.

In your example the directory `cr` is the storage used by `encfs`. The content of this is no big secret, it's encrypted data. You are mounting this data on `mn`, so that you can see its contents in a human-readable way, as files under `mn`.

Only the user that mounts `cr` will be able to read what's inside `mn`. Not even root can. If you want `root` to see the contents, then you should change your `./e.sh 1` in the example to `sudo ./e.sh 1`.

Comment: Regular user don't have access too.

Comment: The user that ran `./e.sh 1` above should be able to access it.

Comment: But haven't access

Answer (score 2):

Using `encfs` in a expect script is different when executing a command because `encfs` forks a background process, but when the expect script exits, the `encfs` daemon becomes defunct. Sooner or later it'll get reclaimed by init.

So you may want to try using `encfs -f` to keep `encfs` running in the foreground and do not exit the script.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But with -f its don't work to. I have same problem in similar script in davfs. Its stack on stage of creating pid file in /var/run/mount.davfs/.